# Python Datetime.datetime is not giving me results in mongodb aggregate

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-datetime

`startTime` and `endTime` is a `datetime` object, same query gives me the desired results on Mongodb Compass.

```py
pl = [
  {
    "$match": {
      "clientId": id_,
      "Date": {
        "$gt": startTime,
        "$lt": endTime
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "Date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Intake",
      "let": { "searchId": { "$toObjectId": "$intakeId" } },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$searchId" ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "PatientID": 1,
            "First Name": 1,
            "Last Name": 1,
            "Status": 1,
            "StatusDate": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "info"
    }
  }
]

cursor = mydb.transaction.aggregate(pl)
```

Comment: Is `"clientId": id_,` correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct..